# Obtener ip publica del equipo C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc

Estoy tratando de obtener la ip publica del equipo. Además de información adicional como el tipo de navegador y la localización de la ip publica obtenida.
Una de mis principales dudas es saber si existe algún sitio donde se pueda obtener dicha información y que este sea confiable, o si existe algún otro método de obtenerla.
Pude obtener la ip de la siguiente manera:

`HttpWebRequest wq= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com");
HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)wq.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
wr.Close();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");            
    Console.WriteLine(externalip);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jV6GFz

Las peticiones a APIs se realizan sin interface de navegador. Ten en cuenta que si tu IP está dinámicamente configurada te devolverán resultados diferentes a lo largo del tiempo. Otras formas de obtenerla (a través de la consola de comandos):

```
curl http://ipinfo.io/ip

wget -qO- http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com
```

Para la localización puedes probar esta API:

```
curl http://ip-api.com/json
```

Para obtener el navegador desde el que ejecutas código Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/mondeja/vuq65x55/1/